# Не работает функция PDO

Tags: php, pdo

До определенного момента все работало, после того, как сделал условия, перестало :с
Ошибок не выдает, но с базой ничего не делает ни в одном из вариантов.

```
    function addToDB($funcSteamId, $funcSteamVisits, $funcSteamFavs) {

$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dev', 'root', 'root');

$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(steamID) FROM guidesStats WHERE steamID=:inputID");
$query->execute(array(':inputID' => $funcSteamId));
$result = $query->fetchAll();

if ($result[0][0] == 1) {
    echo "Запись с таким steamID уже существует, обновляю данные...";
    $affectedRows = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO guidesStats WHERE steamID=:inputID (visitors,favs) VALUES (:inputVisits, :inputFavs)');
    $affectedRows->execute(array(':inputID' => $funcSteamId, ':inputVisits' => $funcSteamVisits, ':inputFavs' => $funcSteamFavs));
}
if ($result[0][0] < 1) {
    $affectedRows = $connection->exec('INSERT INTO guidesStats (steamID,visitors,favs) VALUES (' . $funcSteamId . ',' . $funcSteamVisits . ',' . $funcSteamFavs . ')');
    echo "Добавлена запись в БД";
}
if ($result[0][0] > 1) {
    echo "В БД >1 записи";
}
return 0;
}
```

Примеры **var_dump($result)**:

Для **$funcSteamId = 1**

```
       array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["COUNT(steamID)"]=> string(1) "3" [0]=> string(1) "3" } }
```

Для **$funcSteamId = 7**

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["COUNT(steamID)"]=> string(1) "0" [0]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

Для **$funcSteamId = 1120193385**

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["COUNT(steamID)"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

Вот так выглядит моя БД:

[image: БД]

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всё же для того, что Вы пишете использовать решение на стороне БД. Для  начала добавить уникальный индекс (если этого уже не сделано).

```
ALTER TABLE `guidesStats` ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`steamID`)
```

Затем заменить эту чудовищную схему времён 90-х: проверка "есть ли значение в базе уже?", если да, то "обновить", если нет, то "вставить". Зачем так делать, когда "всё уже придумали до нас"?

```
INSERT INTO `guidesStats` (`steamID`,`visitors`,`favs`)
VALUES (:inpudID, :inputVisits, :inputFavs)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `visitors` = VALUES(`visitors`),
    `favs`     = VALUES(`favs`);
```

Если Вам всё же по каким-то религиозным соображениям требуется именно такая схема как есть - то у Вас просто ошибка синтаксиса в запросе на обновление, должно быть вот так:

```
UPDATE `guidesStats` SET
    `visitors` = :inputVisits,
    `favs`     = :inputFavs
WHERE `steamID` = :inputID
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать обращения к базе в усовиях по примеру до условий.
В 2 шага prepare и execute. Можно добавить try для поимки ошибок.

```
$zapros = 'INSERT INTO DB ($value[0], $value[1]) VALUES';
try {
$var = $connection->prepare($zapros);
$var->bindValue (0, $value[0])
$var->bindValue (1, $value[1])
$var->execute();
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Запрос не очень..";
   $error_output = $connection->errorInfo();
//либо trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $connection. ' Error: ' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
};

if(isset($error_output)) print_r($error_output);
```

если не секрет, то зачем в конце return false?
Если ничего не нужно возвращать, то можно удалить строку return целиком.
Если есть возможность, для теста, попробуйте этот же код только без переменных, просто напишите запрос текстом и посмотрите на результат, если заработает, то добавите переменные.

### правка

Вместо

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT COUNT(steamID) FROM guidesStats WHERE steamID=:inputID");
```

уберите COUNT

```
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT steamID FROM guidesStats WHERE steamID=:inputID");
```

Answer (score 0):

передавать нужно просто массив с данными, не нужно писать для ключа `:` Пишите просто название ключа и все. В execute я имею ввиду.

Comment: я тоже так думал, но, всё-таки можно и так и так.